# I dont want to show shortcode in <pre> tag

Tags: shortcode

I have a theme and I want to show vistors how shortcode format is in `<pre>` tag. But when I add shortcode in `<pre>`, it shows what shortcode does. I just want to show shortcode format in plain text. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**A)** If you want to show the *shortcode syntax* you can try to write it with *double brackets* in the editor:

```
<pre>[[shortcode foo="bar"]]</pre>
```

It will then display as

```
<pre>[shortcode foo="bar"]</pre>
```

on your frontend and it will not activate the shortcode callback.

**B)** Or if you want some extra formatting, you could define your own *pretty format* via shortcode:

```
function pretty_shortcode( $atts, $content ) 
{        
    $atts = shortcode_atts( 
                array( 'class => 'pretty_shortcode' ), 
                $atts, 
                'pretty_shortcode' 
            );

    // input
    $content           = wp_kses( $content, array() );
    $atts['class']     = esc_attr( $atts['class'] );

    // output                       
    return sprintf( '<pre class="%s">%s</pre>', $atts['class'], $content );             
}

add_shortcode( 'pretty_shortcode', 'pretty_shortcode' );
```

You would then write for example this in your editor:

```
[pretty_shortcode class="pretty"]
    [gallery ids="123,321" link="file"]
[/pretty_shortcode]
```

and the output would be:

```
<pre class="pretty">
    [gallery ids="123,321" link="file"]
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

A more crazy but reliable workaround. You can paste the invisible space char `&#173;` after the first bracket. I use that approach to workaround a lot of rendering problems when presenting code. In javascipt the syntax model is:

```
content = content.replace('[', '[' + String.fromCharCode('173'));
```

The tricky part is to grab the character in unicode format and paste in PHP protocol. Otherwise the ­ `&#173;` will be rendered or converted into a `-` hyphen. The char is invisible for the cursor, so you cant select it alone. However, just produce it once with javascript and copy the `[g` part and paste/ replace in the editor.

You can use the same trick to always use  element without captions, in wordpress, by pasting a invisible space as caption on single images.

Here is the shortcode with the space. Paste in your wordpress editor and back-delete each char. After the `g` the cursor stops, before contiune with deleteing the bracket...

```
[­gallery link="none"]
```

Note, if you see `-` instead, your encoding is wrong or the information got broken in the copy by your device. ­­­­­